# Batch find string in variable

Tags: string, batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I'm trying to check if a certain output (!output!) contains a specific string ("ENABLED").

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F %%C IN (%nodeFile%) DO (
set output=dashd-cli masternodelist status %%C
!output!
IF NOT "!output!"=="!output:ENABLED=!" (
    echo OFFLINE
)
)
goto :done
```

**The output of !output! is either one of those:**

*When the node is running:*

```
{
    "111.111.111.111:1111" : "ENABLED"
}
```

*When the node isn't running:*

```
{
}
```

Right now it doesn't echo anything while a node isn't showing any output, meaning it can't find the string "ENABLED".

Comment: whats in your `%nodefile%`??

Comment: IP addresses + ports, like this:

111.111.111.111:1111, 
222.222.222.222:2222, 
333.333.333.333:3333, etc.

Comment: Looking at the last question they asked, it is a list containing seperate lines each looking like this `"123.123.123.200:xxxx"` each with a different last octet.

Comment: whats the expected output? the output seems fine to me

Comment: Yes, the output is fine. But when the output does NOT contain the string "ENABLED" it should do: echo OFFLINE. Changed the OP a bit, hope it's more clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just wanting to do something like this?

```dos
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "USEBACKQ" %%a IN ("%nodeFile%") DO (
    dashd-cli masternodelist status %%a|Find "ENABLED"||(Echo= %%a - OFFLINE))
PAUSE
```

Comment: I think so, yes. How can I write that %%a to a file? Something like this?
`dashd-cli masternodelist status %%a|Find "ENABLED"||(Echo= %%a - OFFLINE)||(@echo %%a>> offline.txt))`

Comment: Think I got it, at least it works, unless there's a better way. `dashd-cli masternodelist status %%a|FIND "ENABLED"||(echo OFFLINE) && (@echo %%a>> offline.txt)`